In jxbrowser7.22, there is still an error: Protocol message had invalid UTF-8
I saw on the official website that this problem had been solved in 7.12.2, but the 7.22 I used reported an error.
Although an error is reported, the program can still run.
 EngineOptions engineOptions=EngineOptions.newBuilder(RenderingMode.HARDWARE_ACCELERATED)
                .licenseKey(JXBROWSER_KEY)
                .addScheme(Scheme.HTTPS,params -> {
                    //do something
                    return InterceptUrlRequestCallback.Response.proceed();
                })
                .build();

error msg:com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message had invalid UTF-8
Has anyone ever encountered this problem

What is the error?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There was a regression and we fixed it again in 7.24.
